# Merge two Lists in C# and merge objects with the same id into one list item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have already thought about how I'm going to solve this by rolling my own solution, but I wondered if .NET already has the functionality for what I'm trying to acheive - if so, I'd rather use something built-in.

Suppose I have two instances of a `Widget` object, let's call them `PartA` and `PartB`. The information from each has been garnered from two different web services, but both have matching IDs.

```
PartA
{
    ID: 19,
    name: "Percy",
    taste: "",
    colour: "Blue",
    shape: "",
    same_same: "but different"
}

PartB
{
    ID: 19,
    name: "",
    taste: "Sweet",
    colour: "",
    shape: "Hexagon",
    same_same: "but not the same"
}
```

I want to merge these to create the following:

```
Result
{
    ID: 19,
    name: "Percy",
    taste: "Sweet",
    colour: "Blue",
    shape: "Hexagon",
    same_same: "but different"
}
```

Notice how the value for `same_same` differs between each, but we consider PartA the master, so the result retains the value `but different`.

Now to complicate matters:

Suppose we have two lists:

```
List<Widget> PartA = getPartA();
List<Widget> PartB = getPartB();
```

Now here's some pseudocode describing what I want to do:

```
List<Widget> Result = PartA.MergeWith(PartB).MergeObjectsOn(Widget.ID).toList();
```

Comment: Just a really non-smart way of doing it. Completely manual: loop through each list and build a new list of merged objects - which I have also merged manually (i.e. hard coded). It does the job, but it really sucks and will be annoying to maintain. I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write your own extension method(s), something like this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> other) where T : ICanMerge
    {
        var otherItems = other.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return (T)item.MergeWith(otherItems[item.Key]);
        }
    }
    public static string AsNullIfEmpty(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return null;
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Where `ICanMerge` is like:

```
public interface ICanMerge
{
    object Key { get; }
    ICanMerge MergeWith(ICanMerge other);
}
```

Implemented e.g. like:

```
public class Widget : ICanMerge
{
    object ICanMerge.Key { get { return this.ID; } }
    int ID {get;set;}
    string taste {get;set;}
    public ICanMerge MergeWith(ICanMerge other)
    {
        var merged = new Widget();
        var otherWidget = (Widget)other;
        merged.taste = this.taste.AsNullIfEmpty() ?? otherWidget.taste;
        //...
        return merged;
    }
}
```

Then it's as simple as `PartA.MergeWith(PartB).ToList()`.

Comment: Way to go the extra mile, Tim! I was expecting a point in the right direction, but you seem to have provided a solution (and much better than what I'm currently using). Thanks very much :). I'm going to try this out and get back to you with an "accept".

Comment: When I tried this, it only lets me do MergeWith against the object (eg Widget), not against the entire list, which would mean doing a foreach and doing the merge for each item (after finding a match for each).  Pretty sure that's not this was meant to be used, but why isn't MergeWith one of my options as an extension for IEnumerable lists?

Comment: @mppowe Did you change it to `this T source` instead of `this IEnumerable<T> source`? That's the only thing I can think of that would explain what you describe.

Comment: Never mind... I don't know why it wasn't showing before, now it is.  Maybe I didn't give Intellisense a chance to catch up or something.  Anyway, yes it did work.  One thing worth noting is that if the lists are of different sizes, the first list (PartA in the above example) must be the smaller one.  Otherwise you get a KeyNotFoundException.  Thanks again for the above code Tim, it's pretty cool

Answer (score 2):

If your lists are one for one (i.e. same number of items and each item in the PartA list has a match in the PartB list), then I would consider the [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method. Note that Zip does not actually require each list to have same number of items. However, if you can't rely on "pairing up" items with matching IDs, then my simplistic approach won't work.

You could do something like this:

```
var alist = GetPartAWidgets().OrderBy(w => w.ID);
var blist = GetPartBWidgets().OrderBy(w => w.ID);
var merged = alist.Zip(blist, (a,b) => new Widget()
             {
               ID = a.ID,
               Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name) ? b.Name : a.Name,
               //etc. 
             });
```

If you want your linq to look cleaner, you could encapsulate the individual Widget merging logic in a function or extension method and use that instead of the inline delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public interface IMerge<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<IMergeMatched<T>> Matched();

    IEnumerable<IMergeMatched<T>> Matched(Func<T, T, bool> predicate);

    IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedBySource();

    IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedBySource(Func<T, bool> predicate);

    IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedByTarget();

    IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedByTarget(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}

public interface IMergeMatched<out T>
{
    T Source { get; }

    T Target { get; }
}

public static class Enumerable
{
    public static IMerge<TSource> Merge<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> target,
                                             Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return new Merge<TSource>(source, target, predicate);
    }
}

public class Merge<T> : IMerge<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _predicate;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _source;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _target;
    private IEnumerable<IMergeMatched<T>> _matcheds;
    private IEnumerable<T> _notMatchedBySource;
    private IEnumerable<T> _notMatchedByTarget;

    public Merge(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> taget, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        _source = source;
        _target = taget;
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMergeMatched<T>> Matched()
    {
        if (_matcheds == null)
        {
            Analize();
        }
        return _matcheds;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMergeMatched<T>> Matched(Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Matched()
            .Where(t => predicate.Invoke(t.Source, t.Target))
            .ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedBySource()
    {
        if (_notMatchedBySource == null)
        {
            Analize();
        }
        return _notMatchedBySource;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedBySource(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return NotMatchedBySource()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedByTarget()
    {
        if (_notMatchedByTarget == null)
        {
            Analize();
        }
        return _notMatchedByTarget;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> NotMatchedByTarget(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return NotMatchedByTarget()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToArray();
    }

    private void Analize()
    {
        var macheds = new List<MergeMached<T>>();
        var notMachedBySource = new List<T>(_source);
        var notMachedByTarget = new List<T>(_target);

        foreach (var source in _source)
        {
            foreach (var target in _target)
            {
                var macth = _predicate.Invoke(source, target);
                if (!macth) continue;

                macheds.Add(new MergeMached<T>(source, target));
                notMachedBySource.Remove(source);
                notMachedByTarget.Remove(target);
            }
        }

        _matcheds = macheds.ToArray();
        _notMatchedBySource = notMachedBySource.ToArray();
        _notMatchedByTarget = notMachedByTarget.ToArray();
    }
}

public class MergeMached<T> : IMergeMatched<T>
{
    public MergeMached(T source, T target)
    {
        Source = source;
        Target = target;
    }

    public T Source { get; private set; }

    public T Target { get; private set; }
}
```

How to use?

```
var source = new List<MediaFolder>
            {
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id1",
                        Name = "Name1",
                        Path = "Path1"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id2",
                        Name = "Name2",
                        Path = "Path2"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id3",
                        Name = "Name3",
                        Path = "Path3"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id4",
                        Name = "Name4",
                        Path = "Path4"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id5",
                        Name = "Name5",
                        Path = "Path5"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id6",
                        Name = "Name6",
                        Path = "Path6"
                    }
            };

        var target = new List<MediaFolder>
            {
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id1",
                        Name = "Actualizado en el objeto",
                        Path = "Path1"
                    },
                    //Id2 eliminado
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id3",
                        Name = "Name3",
                        Path = "Actualizado tambien"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id4",
                        Name = "Name4",
                        Path = "Path4"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id5",
                        Name = "Name5",
                        Path = "Path5"
                    },
                new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id6",
                        Name = "Name6",
                        Path = "Path6"
                    },
                     new MediaFolder
                    {
                        Id = "Id7",
                        Name = "Nuevo Item 7",
                        Path = "Nuevo Item 7"
                    }
            };

        var merge = source.Merge(target, (x, y) => x.Id == y.Id);

        var toUpdate = merge.Matched((x, y) => x.Name != y.Name | x.Path != y.Path)
            .ToArray();

        var toDelete = merge.NotMatchedBySource();
        var toInsert = merge.NotMatchedByTarget();

        Assert.AreEqual(2, toUpdate.Count());
        Assert.IsTrue(toUpdate.Count(x => x.Source.Id == "Id1" & x.Target.Id == "Id1") > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(toUpdate.Count(x => x.Source.Id == "Id3" & x.Target.Id == "Id3") > 0);

        Assert.AreEqual("Id7", toInsert.First().Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("Id2", toDelete.First().Id);
```